# First app in Android Studio won't start

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building my first app in android studio but my app crash when I try to open it. I am very new to this and I don't even know what I can show you to solve my problem.

What should I do to solve this problem?

This is what i get from logcat:

> --------- beginning of crash
>   09-06 06:45:25.516 4182-4182/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.example.android.questionnaireapplication, PID: 4182
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.questionnaireapplication/com.example.android.questionnaireapplication.QuestionnaireActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
>                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554)
>                                                        at com.example.android.questionnaireapplication.QuestionnaireActivity.mettreÀJourQuestion(QuestionnaireActivity.java:38)
>                                                        at com.example.android.questionnaireapplication.QuestionnaireActivity.onCreate(QuestionnaireActivity.java:49)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: Refer to the stacktrace. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html

Comment: I am trying to use stacktrace but where exactly does the stacktrace is created ? I can't find any when my app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below portion of stacktrace should be useful for you as it says that you have a problem on **line 38** in **QuestionnaireActivity.java** which is actually a resource not found exception, i-e string resource you are using to set text in your text view is not a valid resource.

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource ID #0x0 at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331) at
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554) at
>   com.example.android.questionnaireapplication.QuestionnaireActivity.mettreÀJourQuestion(QuestionnaireActivity.java:38)
>   at